# MPI import works with sbatch but fails with srun

Tags: python, mpi, slurm

I'm facing a strange problem when trying to use MPI on a cluster, which uses Slurm as a job scheduler. On both cases, I'm trying to run this simple python program:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
print('TEST')
```

Creating a batch script (where I export the suitable virtual environment and run this python program) and using it with sbatch works great.

However, using srun in the terminal to run the same program (inside the same virtual environment) produces the following error:

```
*** An error occurred in MPI_Init_thread
*** on a NULL communicator
*** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
***    and potentially your MPI job)
[w7:564843] Local abort before MPI_INIT completed successfully, but am not able to aggregate error messages, and not able to guarantee that all other processes were killed!
srun: error: w7: task 0: Exited with exit code 1
```

If I don't import MPI, the python script is executed correctly both with srun and sbatch.

Slurm version is: 19.05.5

OpenMPI version is: 4.0.3

What is the difference between srun and sbatch that makes the former fail and the later work when using MPI? What should I change to make this code run correctly using srun?

Comment: "running the same code with srun" Clarify. Srun inside the script? Run the script with srun? This needs more details. Basically, you're not telling us what you are doing.

Comment: I edited my post to make it more clear. I meant using srun in the terminal (so outside the batch script) to run the python program.

Comment: You should always copy/paste the full error message, especially when it contains hints on how to solve the issue.

Comment: This is unfortunately the full error message that I am getting.

Comment: my bad, the full error message started in Open MPI 4.1 series. Possible fixes are to build Open MPI with SLURM's PMI support or build SLURM with PMIx support. A workaround is to `srun env -u SLURM_NODELIST ./a.out`

Comment: Thank you for your answer Gilles. Unsetting the SLURM_NODELIST environment variable seems to fix the issue indeed. Would it be possible for you to give any explanation for it? I was a bit surprised that it worked, as it seems that both srun and sbatch sets SLURM_NODELIST in a similar way. If you write an answer I can mark it as accepted.

Using PMI support was actually the reason for which I'm trying to use srun instead of sbatch (or inside a batch script). So I experience the same problem in that case.

Comment: Actually when running simple mpi jobs with 2 processes like this: srun -n2 env -u SLURM_NODELIST ./a.out, both processes have rank 0, which is obviously problematic. Running it with pmi2 support produces the same behavior. Using mpirun inside an sbatch script (without using srun nor env) produces the correct behaviour. Do you have any insight about that?

Comment: Unsetting `SLURM_NODELIST` can only work with with single task MPI job. Under the hood, Open MPI refuses to start in singleton mode if SLURM is detected **and** `SLURM_NODELIST` is set, and (tries to) use PMI(1/2/x) instead. The workaround was to trick Open MPI into starting in singleton mode.

Comment: Did you build Open MPI with pmi support? (e.g. `configure --with-slurm[=/path/to/slurm]`) what does `srun --mpi=list` says? if there is no default provider (or you want to change it), you have to `srun --mpi=pmi2 a.out`.

Comment: There was some bug that was preventing me to use pmix support ( some missing symbolic link, see: https://linux.debian.bugs.dist.narkive.com/wxMHknxm/bug-954272-slurmd-slurm-not-working-with-openmpi#post4 ). Using srun with pmix_v3 actually solves the issue. Using pmi2 instead produces the same issue. I have to admit I have little knowledge about pmix and pmi2 so I have no idea why it works with one and not the other. In any case, thanks a lot Gilles for spending time helping me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the job with srun and with pmix support ( srun --mpi=pmix_v3 a.out ) seems to completely solve the issue. For more information about using slurm with pmix support: https://slurm.schedmd.com/mpi_guide.html

I was unaware that our OpenMPI was built without pmi2 support, so this explains why it didn't work with pmi2

Comment: Open MPI does support PMIx, but PMI1/PMI2 support is not built by default, so you first need to make sure your Open MPI was built with PMI1/PMI2 support (e.g. `configure --with-slurm ...`

Comment: You're completely right. It's a bit embarassing as I was convinced our OpenMPI was built with PMI2 support, but it actually wasn't. Once again, thanks a lot for your help.